# TS: Redux Actions without type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I recently started using Typescript in my react projects.
One piece i'm missing is typing dispatch and action creators.

I'm using my own type of actions based on: https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate

My actions are coded like:

```
export function getXXX(){ 
  return {
    types: [ 
        ActionTypes.GET_XXX, 
        ActionTypes.GET_XXX_SUCCESS, 
        ActionTypes.GET_XXX_ERROR 
    ],
    request: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `/v1/retrievexxx`
    }
  }    
}
```

My problem is that type is missing (obviously) and the ReduxAction TS types require a Type.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Personally I use [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) but that would mean you need to rewrite your current code

Comment: Would be a massive refactor :-) ... I could however keep the baseType GET_XXX as type and only provide SUCCESS/ERROR in the array ... then i coult type my actions with the default typings ...

Comment: I'll second [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions). There's plenty of clever stuff in it that the average TS user could never hope to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend *not* trying to work around this, and always provide a `type` for your actions. There is a reason why the `Action` type in the Redux typings requires it: big parts of the Redux ecosystem - such as the Dev Tools - expect it to be there, and will act weirdly if it's not. So it's probably not worth going against the grain here.

Comment: I do provide types, an array of as stated in https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate. The middleware handles the request, success and failure types by dispatching them.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, it's important to realize that the object you dispatch is simply not an `Action` in the Redux sense - which is totally fine. It's the same way redux-thunk works - you dispatch a function instead of an action, but it will be actions once things get to the actual store. So what you need to do not to make this appear like an action, but to type your middleware so that `dispatch` also accepts your type of objects. I suggest looking at the redux-thunk typings for how to do this.